# Orders of Galois Field

Tags: finite-fields

Here's what I'm working on:

> Find the orders of all the nonzero elements of $GF(2, x^4+x+1)$.

I believe I should approach it the same way I did for the orders of the roots of unity in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137010/finding-the-elements-of-sqrt91), but am not sure what to do. Would a cyclic table come in handy for this type of problem?

Comment: After you have followed Henning's advice you can check your answer by comparing it to [the table I prepared for referrals like this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619). What I denote $\gamma$ there is the coset of $x$ modulo the ideal generated by $x^4+x+1$ (your book/lecture notes might call it something else).

Comment: I appreciate the reference Jyrki Lahtonen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, in this case of order $15$.

Since, clearly, $x$ has neither order $3$ nor $5$, it must be a generator of the multiplicative group.

So all you need to do is find the canonical form of $x^3, x^6, x^9, x^{12}$ (which have order 5) and $x^5, x^{10}$ (which have order 3), and then everything else (except, of course, $1$) has order 15.